# What can (and should) I do if Drop panics? Can I free other resources anyway?

Tags: rust, destructor, panic, drop, exception-safety

I've got a simple resource which uses `MaybeUninit` and `unsafe` for external reasons:

```rust
pub struct Resource<'a, T> {
    repr: std::cell::RefMut<'a, std::mem::MaybeUninit<T>>
}
impl<'a, T> Drop for Resource<'a, T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { // Safety: `MaybeUninit<T>` is always initialized here.
            std::ptr::drop_in_place(self.repr.as_mut_ptr());
        }
    }
}
```

I guess, if `T::drop()` panics, the `RefMut` gets leaked, poisoning its `RefCell`. How can I prevent this and would it be idiomatic to do so? The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) states:

> Given that a `panic!` will call `drop` as it unwinds, any `panic!` in a `drop` implementation will likely abort.

but that "likely" doesn't make it clear enough whether I should expect (and can handle) this scenario.

Comment: "but that "likely" doesn't make it clear enough whether I should expect (and can handle) this scenario." a double panic (panic during unwinding) is a hard abort, you literally can't handle it.

Comment: @Masklinn what about a "single" panic occurring in an ordinary `drop` (which isn't caused by a panic)?

Comment: `drops` get called during unwinding, regardless of whether the unwinding was triggered from a `drop` or from other non-drop code.

Comment: In general you should write `Drop::drop` assuming that any other `drop` you invoke, implicit or explicit, will not panic. For other cases, you may check `std::thread::panicking()` and avoid panicking there.